# html ascii code "not well formed" error

Tags: html

I'm working on a webpage in spanish an english, so I have to use special characters like á, é, etc.

For this i took this info of codes: http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

and I wrote a:

```
<h3>Energ&#237a;</h3>
```

but on the error console it says this: **not well-formed** I had it with no ; but then I put it, but the error is still there, any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What character set are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to flip the semicolon and the "a":

```
<h3>Energ&#237;a</h3>
```